# When do you use amortized time complexity and when to use unamortized?

Tags: time-complexity, amortized-analysis

This is my guess:

-Use `amortized` because we want to know the "averaged" complexity over `n` operations assuming the operation is going to be used frequently

-Use `unamortized` when you know the operation is going to be used rarely

Comment: (try spaces following the dashes of a list) There is *late answers are wrong answers*: *real time* processing.

Comment: I just did and I got bullet points as hyphens and some kind of blocks around the words. PS: I have no idea what you're saying after the parenthesis

Comment: `I have no idea …` Nothing to be ashamed of - or proud. en.wikipedia: *Real-time processing **fails** if not completed within a specified deadline relative to an event; deadlines must always be met, regardless of system load*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the motivation for the amortized analysis from [this reference](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs/academic/class/15451-s07/www/lecture_notes/lect0206.pdf):

> The motivation for amortized analysis is that looking at the worst-case time per operation can be too
> pessimistic if the only way to produce an expensive operation is to "set it up" with a large number
> of cheap operations beforehand.

Hence, unamortized (asymptotic) analysis means considering time complexity of an algorithm (instead of each operation) when each operation can be counted in constant time.